# Is it instance? or a class? python paradox

Tags: python, class, oop, decorator

```
  def F(thing):
    class C(object):
       def __init__(self, thing):
          self.inst = thing()
       def deco():
          return "Deco:" + self.inst.who()
    return C

  class worker(object):
     def who(self):
        return "I am a worker"

  worker = F(worker)
  w = worker()
  print(w.deco())
```

Question: what prototype does the function F return(what is "C" when F() return C)? Is it a instance(object)? or a class?

It looked like what F(worker) return is a class, instead of an instance.

The reason is Because if it is an instance, then worker = F(worker) is also an instance, yes?

### Then when calling for the instance: w = worker(), we need a __call__ function in the decorator, C, otherwise we cannot call it. But actually we don't have __call__ here, so it looked like it is a class.

If you admit it , then please look at the following:

```
  class F(object):
    def __init__(self, anything):
       self.anything = anything
    def __call__(self):
       class C(object):
          def __init__(self, thing):
             self.inst = thing()
          def deco():
             return "Deco:" + self.inst.who()
       return C(self.anything())

  class worker(object):
     def who(self):
        return "I am a worker"

  worker = F(worker)
  w = worker()
  print(w.deco())
```

Now, tell me what is the prototype of worker = F(worker) now? In principle, no matter what F() is, it should not affect the prototype of worker, right?

Then "worker"(not worker()) here should be a class, as usual(as we deduced in the first case). But in this case, it is not! because when we call worker = F(worker), for F is a class, then it will initiating an instance by calling __init__! Then now worker is the instance!

Comment: You can return a class or an instance of a class. Actually, classes have a class, too. There is no separations between the two that exists in some other languages' object model.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't even work as is. If you fix your code to actually be valid python, then for your first question, `F` returns a class, `C` which gets instantiated when you say `w = worker()`

```
def F(thing):
    class C(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.inst = thing()
        def deco(self):
            return "Deco:" + self.inst.who()
    return C

class Worker(object):
    def who(self):
        return "I am a worker"

worker = F(Worker)
print(worker)
w = worker()
print(w)
print(w.deco())
```

You would get

```
<class '__main__.C'>
<__main__.C object at 0x2471e4>
Deco:I am a worker
```

For the second question, `F` is creating an instance of itself and when you call that instance, it returns an instance of class `C`.

```
class F(object):
    def __init__(self, anything):
        self.anything = anything
    def __call__(self):
        class C(object):
            def __init__(self, thing):
                self.inst = thing()
            def deco(self):
                return "Deco:" + self.inst.who()
        return C(self.anything)

class Worker(object):
    def who(self):
        return "I am a worker too"

worker = F(Worker)
print(worker)
w = worker()
print(w)
print(w.deco())
```

and you would get

```
<__main__.F object at 0x243444>
<__main__.C object at 0x243b0c>
Deco:I am a worker too
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't get the reason why you Capitalize "worker" of the class. I wrote worker = F(worker) is not a logical false but an expression for "decorator" in python. But still thanks

Comment: Because it's convention to capitalize class names.